# How to import an ActionScript class into a package?

Tags: class, actionscript, import

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a class to import.

Here is my filesystem:

```
 - com
     - test
         - class1.as
     - example
         - class2.as
```

I'm working on class1.as and want to import class2. How can I do that?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
import com.example.class2;
```

How can I access class2 from class1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to import `example.class2` instead of `com.example.class2`? And make sure that the example package is specified in `class2.as`

Comment: The answer to both your questions is yes.

Comment: Could you please send examples of your classes?

Comment: Sorry I haven't got back to this question in a while... anyway, turns out it was something wrong I was doing, and under normal circumstances, my example above should work fine. Anyway, +1 for trying to help.